# looking for algorithm to calculate h-index fast

Tags: algorithm, sorting

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-index

this wiki page is a definition of h-index

basically if I were to have an array of [ 0 3 4 7 8 9 10 ], my h-index would be 4 since I have 4 numbers bigger than 4. My h-index would've been 5 if I were to have 5 numbers bigger than 5, and etc. Given an array of integers bigger or equal to 0, what are the ways of calculating h-index efficiently?

edit: the array is not necessarily sorted

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here my realization **O(N)** with tabling, this is simple and blazing fast:

```cpp
private static int GetHIndex(int[] m)
{
    int[] s = new int[m.Length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < m.Length; i++) s[Math.Min(m.Length, m[i])]++;

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = s.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        sum += s[i];
        if (sum >= i)
            return i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This algorithm is wrong, it should be `if(sum == i) return i;`. But even then it computed that there are `i` numbers which are greater **or equal** than `i` (what is correct according to the link but not to what the questioner wanted to know). In addition if there's no match (and therefore `return`) in the second `for` loop the algorithm returns `0` which means there are zero numbers greater (or greater or equal) than 0 which is contradictory for an (non-empty) array only containing numbers greater or equal than 0 (at least if you check using the relation `>=` as it is done by now).

Comment: No comments? No explanation? The algorithm might be good, but don't force your readers to stare it down, at least share the core idea(s).

Answer (score 2):

This could be done in O(n) time.

1. Find median of the array.
2. if median > (n-1)/2 then the number comes before median. Find it iteratively
3. If median < (n-1)/2 then the number comes after median. Find it iteratively.
4. If median == (n-1)/2 then the median is the solution

Here I am assuming that n is odd. Change algorithm slightly for even n (replace (n+1)/2 with n/2 assuming rank of median is n/2). Also, finding actual median in O(n) time is complicated. Use a good pivot instead (as in quicksort).

Complexity: n+n/2 +n/4... = O(n)

Comment: awsome =D, I guess linear is the best outcome

Comment: This is NLogN, as search of median should be done into all array.

Comment: What about cases when answer not inside array? Example [0 0 0 9 9 9]

Comment: @Толя when you are left with only 1 element and that is not the right solution, then there is no solution.

Comment: @Vikram Bhat 1/2 + 1/4 + ... (up to infinity) = 1, so it is as ElKamina wrote: O(n).

Comment: This algorithm is wrong, take the example `[2,2,2,2,2]`. The median here is `2` and therefore `median == (n-1)/2` leading to the solution `2`. This means there should be exactly two numbers which are greater than 2. Checking the array proves this statement false.

Answer (score 1):

Answer in c# but easily convertable to java as well

```cs
    public int HIndex(int[] citations) {
            Array.Sort(citations);

            var currentCount = 0;
            var length = citations.Length;
            for (var i = citations.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                currentCount = length - i;
                // if the count of items to the right is larger than current value it means thats the max we can expect for hindex

                if (currentCount - 1 >= citations[i])
                {
                    return currentCount - 1;
                }
            }

            return currentCount;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution I could think of. not sure if its the best.

Sort the array in ascending order. complexity **nlog(n)**

Iterate through the array from the index **0 to n**. complexity of **n**

and for each iteration, suppose index is **i**

```
if (arr[i] == (arr.length - (i+1))
    return arr[i]
```

e.g.,

```
arr =[ 0 3 4 7 8 9 10 ]
arr[2] = 4
i = 2
arr.length = 7
4 = (7- (2+1))
```

Comment: No need to sort (O(nlogn)). See my solution which is O(n)

Comment: am sorry. :) that was a typo

Comment: @ElKamina. ya your answer is better

Comment: This algorithm is wrong since it will only return a result if the actual h-index is part of the array. Adding the number `11` to your example (`[0, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]`) should return the solution `5` as there are five numbers greater than 5 but this algorithm won't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is in O(nlogn) time but sort and concise.

```
public static int hindex(int[] array) {
        Arrays.sort(array);
        int pos = 0;
        while (pos < array.length && array[pos] <= array.length - pos) {
            pos++;
        }
        return array[pos - 1];
    }
```

Comment: This returns an element in the array but that won't always be correct, for example, `[0, 2]`, the answer should be 1.  Also this solution doesn't work for cases like `[4, 5]`.

Answer (score 0):

n=size of array

sort the array

then h-index = max(min(f(i),i) for i=1:n)

since h-index can never exceed n, replace all numbers in array greater
than n with n.

Now use count sort to sort the array.

time complexity O(n)
space complexity O(n)

Answer (score -1):

I was not happy with my previous implementation, so I replaced it with a faster solution written in Java.

```java
public int hIndex(int[] citations) {
    if(citations == null || citations.length == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    Arrays.sort(citations);

    int hIndex = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<citations.length;i++)
    {
        int hNew;

        if(citations[i]<citations.length-i)
        {
            hNew = citations[i];

            if(hNew>hIndex)
            {
                hIndex = hNew;
            }
        }
        else if(citations[i]>=citations.length-i)
        {
            hNew = citations.length-i;

            if(hNew>hIndex)
            {
                hIndex = hNew;
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    return hIndex;
}
```